# Insert character in a file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, file

Hello I have a problem in bash.
i have a file and i am trying insert a point in the final line of each line:

```
cat file | sed s/"\n"/\\n./g  > salida.csv
```

but not works =(.

Because i need count the lines with a word
 I need count the lines with the same country

and if i do a grep the grep take colombia and colombias.

And other question how i can count lines with the same country?

for example

```
1 colombia
2 brazil
3 ecuador
4 colombias
5 colombia

colombia 2
colombias 1
ecuador 1
brazil 1
```

Comment: @Kevin you can post an answer

Comment: Provide examples so we understand what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: 1 colombia
    2 brazil
    3 ecuador
    4 colombias
    5 colombia
colombia appears twice ->
    colombia 2 colombia appears once in the file etc.

Comment: @Kent I wasn't quite clear that that was what he was actually doing. And besides, posting as an answer requires me to add actual text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since a sed solution was posted (probably the best tool for this task), I'll contribute an awk

```
awk '$NF=$NF"."' file > salida.csv
```

Update:

```
$ cat input
1 colombia
2 brazil
3 ecuador
4 colombias
5 colombia

$ awk '{a[$2]++}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' input
brazil 1
colombias 1
ecuador 1
colombia 2
```

...and, please stop updating your question with different questions...

Comment: Ok. But finally question what is a? and how you relates the awk with the cat?

Comment: @BenitoCamelas You don't need `cat`. `awk`, `sed` et al can deal with files themselves. See also [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). `a` is a temporary array used to construct the output you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
cut -f2 -d' ' salida.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Great solution for what appears (currently) to be the OP's real problem.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line has a few problems.  Some that matter, some that are style choices, but here's my take:

1. Unnecessary `cat`.  `sed` can take a filename as an argument.
2. Your `sed` command doesn't need the `g`. Since each line only has one end, there's no reason to tell it to look for more.
3. Don't look for the newline character, just match the end of line with `$`.

That leaves you with:

```
sed s/$/./ file > salida.csv
```

Edit:

If your real question is "How do I grep for `colombia`, but not match `colombias`?", you just need to use the `-w` flag to match whole words:

```
grep -w colombia file
```

If you want to count them, just add `-c`:

```
grep -c -w colombia file
```

Read the [`grep(1)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/grep/) for more information.

Comment: But how can i count the other countrys?. i have 2 colombia, but i have other countrys that i don't know but the countrys are in the file

Comment: You've been continually editing your question to ask different things.  You can hardly blame us if our answers don't match new information you've added after the fact.